# Infinite loop with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following script

```
SELECT
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [RefAbacus]), * 
INTO 
    #CI
FROM 
    [CI]
WHERE 
    [RefAbacus] = @RefAbacus
ORDER BY 
    date, TypeOperation

SELECT
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [RefAbacus]), * 
INTO 
    #DBRapproEchRemb
FROM 
    [DBTmpRapproEchRemb]
WHERE 
    [RefAbacus] = @RefAbacus
ORDER BY 
    date, TypeOperation

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 ON #CI ([RefAbacus], RowNum)
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_2 ON #DBRapproEchRemb ([RefAbacus], RowNum)

--declaration des variables
DECLARE @MaxRownum int
SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #CI) 

DECLARE @MinRownum int
SET @MinRownum = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #CI)

DECLARE @FR int;
DECLARE @LR int;
DECLARE @inte int;
DECLARE @R int;
DECLARE @remboursement AS float
DECLARE @LastInterestDate AS nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @TolerancePart int;

SET @FR = @MinRownum
SET @LR = @MaxRownum
SET @TolerancePart = 5000;

SET @R = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #CI)
SET @inte = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #CI)

WHILE @R <= @MaxRownum
BEGIN
      WAY:
        --ELSE
        --BEGIN
        SET @LastInterestDate = ''
        SET @inte = (SELECT
          MIN(RowNum)
        FROM #CI)
        WHILE @inte <= @MaxRownum
        BEGIN -- run your operation here
          IF ((SELECT
              Date
            FROM #CI
            WHERE RowNum = @inte)
            <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
          BEGIN

            IF ((SELECT
                EchInteret
              FROM #CI
              WHERE RowNum = @inte)
              IS NOT NULL and (SELECT
                    [Remboursement]
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R)IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN

              IF ((SELECT
                  EchInteret
                FROM #CI
                WHERE RowNum = @inte)
                <> 0)
              BEGIN


                IF ((SELECT
                    [Remboursement]
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R)
                  > (SELECT
                    EchInteret
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte)
                  )
                BEGIN ---------------------------------------
                  PRINT 'update 1'
                  UPDATE #CI
                  SET [Remboursement] = R.[Remboursement] - INTE.EchInteret
                  FROM (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R) R
                    ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                  WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R
                  AND #CI.[Remboursement] IS NOT NULL;





                  UPDATE #DBRapproEchRemb
                  SET [PartEnInterêt] = EchInteret
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte
                  AND #DBRapproEchRemb.EchInteret IS NOT NULL;

                  UPDATE #CI
                  SET EchInteret = 0
                  FROM #CI

                  WHERE #CI.RowNum = @inte


                END
                ELSE -------------------------
                 IF ((SELECT
                    [Remboursement]
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R)
                  <= (SELECT
                    EchInteret
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte)
                  )
                BEGIN
                  PRINT 'update 2'
                  UPDATE #DBRapproEchRemb
                  SET [PartEnInterêt] = INTE.[PartEnInterêt] + R.Remboursement
                  FROM (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R) R
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #DBRapproEchRemb
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE
                    ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                  WHERE #DBRapproEchRemb.RowNum = @inte;


                  SELECT
                    INTE.[PartEnInterêt],
                    R.Remboursement
                  FROM (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R) R
                  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #DBRapproEchRemb
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE
                    ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                  WHERE INTE.RowNum = @inte;

                  UPDATE INTE
                  SET EchInteret = INTE.EchInteret - R.Remboursement
                  FROM (SELECT
                    *
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @R
                  AND Remboursement IS NOT NULL) R
                  INNER JOIN #CI
                  INTE
                    ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                  WHERE INTE.RowNum = @inte
                  AND INTE.EchInteret IS NOT NULL;


                  UPDATE #CI
                  SET Remboursement = 0
                  WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R
                  AND #CI.Remboursement IS NOT NULL; ;

                --------------------------------------------

                END;
                BREAK;
              END;
            END

            IF ((SELECT
                [Remboursement]
              FROM #CI
              WHERE RowNum = @R)
              IS NOT NULL and (SELECT
                      EchPrincial
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @inte
                   )

                    IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
              IF (SELECT
                  [Remboursement]
                FROM #CI
                WHERE RowNum = @R
           )
                <> 0
              BEGIN
                IF ((SELECT
                    EchPrincial
                  FROM #CI
                  WHERE RowNum = @inte
                )
                  <> 0)
                BEGIN

                  IF ((SELECT
                      [Remboursement]
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @R
                    )
                    > (SELECT
                      EchPrincial
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @inte
                    )
                    )
                  BEGIN
                    PRINT 'update 3'
                    UPDATE #CI
                    SET [Remboursement] = R.[Remboursement] - INTE.EchPrincial
                    FROM (SELECT
                      *
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                      *
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @R) R
                      ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                    WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R;

                    UPDATE #DBRapproEchRemb
                    SET PartEnPrincipal = EchPrincial
                    WHERE RowNum = @inte;


                    UPDATE #CI
                    SET EchPrincial = 0
                    WHERE #CI.RowNum = @inte;

                  END

                  -----------
                  ELSE
                    IF ((SELECT
                      [Remboursement]
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @R
                    )
                    <=(SELECT
                      EchPrincial
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @inte
                   )
                    )
                  BEGIN
                    PRINT 'update 4'
                    UPDATE INTE
                    SET [PartEnInterêt] = inte.[PartEnInterêt] + R.Remboursement
                    FROM #DBRapproEchRemb
                    INTE
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                      *
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @R) R
                      ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                    WHERE INTE.RowNum = @inte;


                    UPDATE #CI
                    SET EchPrincial = inte.EchPrincial - R.Remboursement
                    FROM (SELECT
                      *
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                      *
                    FROM #CI
                    WHERE RowNum = @R) R
                      ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
                    WHERE #CI.RowNum = @inte;


                    UPDATE #CI
                    SET Remboursement = 0
                    WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R;

                  END;
                  BREAK;
                END
              END
            END
          END
          SET @inte = @inte + 1;
        END ----end while 
        IF ((SELECT
            [Remboursement]
          FROM #CI
          WHERE RowNum = @R)
          <> 0 and (SELECT
            [Remboursement]
          FROM #CI
          WHERE RowNum = @R)
          is not null)
          GOTO WAY;

        SELECT
          *
        FROM #CI

        SELECT
          *
        FROM #DBRapproEchRemb
        SET @R = @R + 1;




      -------------------------------


      --END

      END
```

There is an infinite loop . How to correct it ?

Comment: And how do you know there is an infinite loop?

Comment: Both your while conditions (@R & @inte) increment, so this shouldn't be an infinite loop. How many rows are in #CI? Your loop iterates through them in a loop that is inside another loop essentially meaning for every row in the table you iterate through the whole table. This could get out of control very fast, but should not be infinite.